# Anomalous behaviours of fgets()

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

**Input Format**

The first line contains two integers, N and M, separated by a single space, where N represents the number of people, and M represents the number of topics. N lines follow.
Each line contains a binary string of length M. If the ith line's jth character is 1, then the ith person knows the jth topic; otherwise, he doesn't know the topic.

**Constraints**

2≤N≤500
1≤M≤500

**Code**

```
int main() 
{
    int i,j,k,m,n;
    char *str='\0';
    //n - no of persons
    //m - no of topics

    //Read the m and n from console
    scanf("%d %d\n",&n,&m);

    //Allocate the memory
    str=malloc(501);


    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        if(fgets(str,501,stdin)!=NULL)
        {
            if(strlen(str)>0 && str[strlen(str)-1]=='\n')
                str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';
        }
        printf("%s\n",str);
    }


    //Free used variables
    free(str);

    return 0;

}
```

**Sample Input 1 -**

```
4 5
10101
11100
11010
00101
```

**Sample Output 1 -**

```
10101
11100
11010
00101
```

**Result : Expected output matches the printed output.**

**Sample Input 2 -**

```
4 500 
11100110111100111011001010001110110100111111100111110111100111000110110011111111001001010111111111011011110000111001101011110101011100111011001011110100011011001110110111110010111010100001111011111110110111010101101001111100010111011110011111100110011101110111100110010110111111011010110110011101001011110101110100110011010101111011101111010100011101110110101110101101010110101010111111111001100001110100011010110101110110111111111111111001100101110111110110011010011101110100010111110000000110110110    
10101010101001110011110110011101111001011001110101011101111110101011011110010100110011110111111010100001111111111010101111110110111101110101111111100010011011101010111011111010111001111110101110111011100010110101001001001101110111110111011111111101110010100110110011111100101010100001111111111010011001111101010011111110111011001001110111010111111111011011010011101101000010101010011110100111111110101011110011110001110111111011101100011100101100101111111110011101001110101011111001111100111110010001    
11111101101110110110111101101111111111110001110100111001010111011011011111011111111010010101111011000101001101110100111111111001110111111101000011110100010001010111101010111111111010111011011110000111010111101011110111100110010000001111111101101110110010010111010111100010100000010011111001100101101011101111000101110110011111110110111111111011010011001000111101101001011101011010010111100001111011001111111001110110011011111011101001001011001111111001011111011111010111010011111010100110110111111100    
11111000011111101111111101001100011011111110011110110111011111111100110100011100011111011111011111001010010110110111111000100110111101111000111101100001110000101010011001101101100011000001111010001111101011000110001111110100101001011011111010001101101110011110101001011100111100011111011110001110100100111111111110100110111011101111000011001101111000101011111001101010111100110011101100100010011111111111011110011100011111111011011110011011101110111110011111011111111101111011110111001111010001111001
```

**Sample Output - 2**

```
11100110111100111011001010001110110100111111100111110111100111000110110011111111001001010111111111011011110000111001101011110101011100111011001011110100011011001110110111110010111010100001111011111110110111010101101001111100010111011110011111100110011101110111100110010110111111011010110110011101001011110101110100110011010101111011101111010100011101110110101110101101010110101010111111111001100001110100011010110101110110111111111111111001100101110111110110011010011101110100010111110000000110110110
10101010101001110011110110011101111001011001110101011101111110101011011110010100110011110111111010100001111111111010101111110110111101110101111111100010011011101010111011111010111001111110101110111011100010110101001001001101110111110111011111111101110010100110110011111100101010100001111111111010011001111101010011111110111011001001110111010111111111011011010011101101000010101010011110100111111110101011110011110001110111111011101100011100101100101111111110011101001110101011111001111100111110010001
```

**Expected Output 2 - It should contain 4 lines of text instead of 2 in the output.**

Comment: Use `int c; while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` instead of `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour. You just want to read characters from `stdin` with `getchar()` until either `'\n'` or EOF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `'\n'` from `scanf("%d %d\n",&n,&m);`.  The `'\n'` complicates input.  *Any* whitespace as a `scanf()` directive like `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'`, etc. matches *any* number of white-space.  So `scanf()` will not return until non-white-space is entered after the 2 numbers.
2. Do not mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`.  Instead use `fgets()` and qualify inputs:

   ```
   char buf[50];
   fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);  // Should also check `fgets() results
   if (2 != sscanf(buf,  "%d%d", &n, &m) || n < 2 || n > 500 || [more tests]) {
     puts("Bad input");
     return 1;
   }
   ```
3. Remove `fflush(stdin);`.
4. Put `printf("%s\n",str);` inside the preceding `if(fgets...` block.
5. **Allocate 502**, not 501.  +1 for the `'\n'` and +1 for the `'\0'`.  This is why your last test case is failing.  Code is trying to read a line with 500 `char` and a `'\n'` which is 501 `char`.  The 501 passed to `fgets()` inidates room for 500 `char` and a terminating null character `'\0'`.
6. `char *str='\0';` is strange.  Suggest `char *str = NULL;`
7. Suggested for loop

   ```
   str = malloc(502);
   for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
     if(fgets(str,502,stdin)!=NULL) {
       if (strlen(str)>0 && str[strlen(str)-1] == '\n')
         str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
       }
       printf("%s\n",str);
     }
   ```

Comment: I've made the changes suggested by you! Now I'm getting an output with first line same as the input..second line complete blank..third line after that a white spaced line.

Comment: The post's "Input Format" does not agree with "Sample Input 2 -".  "Sample Input 2 -" has an extra blank line not detailed in "Input Format".  Which is correct and what are you using?

Comment: I've reduced this input https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/3179/input03.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1426378260&Signature=szmDXvhPon3zEx4ZeblFP%2FOE8Cc%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: #4 and #7 are contradicting each other. Do you think i need to allocate memory inside loop because maybe once the first string is read inside loop we are appending a null character so there might be problems arising for the second scan.

Comment: I missed 502 in `fgets()` . Thanks again!

Comment: @psychoCoder  Missing 502 is a good lesson in programming.  Much better to do something like `#define M_MAX 500  ... if(m > M_MAX) fail();. ... str = malloc(M_MAX + 2); .... fgets(M_MAX + 2) ...`  IOW - avoid magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

1) cleaning the input buffer with `fflush(stdin);` is a bad practice (it works not in any system). Better use a loop like `while(getchar()!='\n');` if you really need to clean `stdin`;

2) getting string size with `strlen(str)` can fail if your line has no `'\0'` character inside, so expression `str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';` can lead to unexpected result (as I understand, you want to set end of string if input was large to be placed in `str` - better use `str[500]='\0';` without using `strlen()`... if input is shorter than 500 `fgets` put `'\0'` in the end);

3) after `malloc(size)` you should check the returned value before using the allocated memory.

Comment: Concerning #2.  OP's `strlen()` is after testing if `fgets()` result was `NULL` and with a buffer size > 1,  In that case ,`fgets()` will insure `str` _always_ have a terminating null character `'\0'`.  `strlen(str)` will not fail.  The suggestion `str[500]='\0';` is not needed.

Comment: Also check for EOF in this `while` loop!

Answer (score 1):

You need room for your 500 characters *and* for both the terminating `\n` *and* the terminating `0`. You only have room for 500 characters plus the terminating zero, so `fgets` does not read the final hard return. As this remains in the input buffer, it gets read next with the next iteration of `\n` (and it should be showing in your output).

Increase the buffer size to 502 to fix. A better alternative is to read the first line and allocate the line buffer size according to the number of characters at that point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But I think there might be some other issue with the code as it still is not giving the desired output after increasing the buffer size.